# what does => mean in oracle pl sql.is it and invoking operator?

Tags: oracle, plsql

i have a code: `OPEN c_data (p_id => 1);`

what does `=>` operator mean in **PL/SQL**

is it a invoking operator or assignment operator

Comment: Check the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00825

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=>` is used in a procedure or function call to perform parameter assignment by name. Let's say we have a procedure defined as:

```
PROCEDURE XYZ(pParm1 IN NUMBER, pParm2 IN NUMBER, pOutput OUT NUMBER);
```

and we want to invoke it. One way is to pass parameters in the order of declaration, as in:

```
XYZ(10, 20, nOut);
```

Another way, which I feel is clearer, is to use the `=>` operator to directly show which values are being assigned to each parameter:

```
XYZ(pOutput => nOut, pParm1 => 20, pParm2 => 40);
```

Note that if you use the `=>` operator to assign values to each parameter it is not necessary to pass the parameters in the order they're declared in the procedure.

If you compile and run the following example:

```
declare 
  nOut  NUMBER;

  PROCEDURE XYZ(pParm1 IN NUMBER, pParm2 IN NUMBER, pOutput OUT NUMBER) IS
  BEGIN
    pOutput := pParm1 * pParm2;
  END XYZ;
begin
  -- Test statements here

  XYZ(10, 20, nOut);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('After call 1, nOut=' || nOut);

  XYZ(pOutput => nOut, pParm1 => 20, pParm2 => 40);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('After call 2, nOut=' || nOut);
end;
```

you'll find it produces the following output:

```
After call 1, nOut=200
After call 2, nOut=800
```

I find that passing values by name is particularly useful in a couple of cases:

1. You have a procedure with a large number of parameters where it's difficult to understand which parameter value is associated with each parameter, or
2. You have a procedure which has default values for most or all of its parameters, and only want to pass in those parameters for which you have values which differ from the defaults.

Share and enjoy.